# Html Bootstrap4 - three columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I created one container with one row with 3 columns but I dont get 3 columns at all I get only one long column with all content. Any idea why? 
I am using Bootstrap 4.

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/config.php'); // Define DIR atc ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title><?php if(isset($title)){ echo $title; }?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>   
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3"><?php include(DIR .'includes/ads.php');?></div>
            <div class="col-lg-5"><?php include(DIR .'includes/article.php');?></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex flex-column"><?php include(DIR .'includes/sidebar.php');?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is your screen resolution? You're setting it to be 3 columns only on "large" displays.

Comment: Thanks. I saw other comments about it my mistake I am new in using Boostrap :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you used the `lg`classes - these are for large monitors. Load it on a large monitor, then you'll see the three next to each other.

If you make the window narrower, they go below each other - that's Bootstrap responsivity;

To get get 3 columns also on smaller screens, use the regular classes, like `col-5`, `col-4` etc. And - and that's the big advantage of Bootstrap - you can also combine several classes for different sizes in the same element, like `<div class="col-6 col-lg-3">`, which would result in 2 columns each on a small monitor or 4 columns each on a large monitor.

In this codepen I put your code on top and then copied it once, using the regular `col-`-classes:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qxRXPK

Comment: Wow my problem was totally in diffrent place I had <div><img src ="#" alt="profile" class="rounded-circle img-fluid>"</div> it take me 30 min to find this >"</div> :D but it was good to learn something more about Bootstrap :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `col-sm` and `col-md` css classes to be more specific for different display resolutions

Comment: Thanks I miss that :D well new to boostrap